# IntelliJ plugin hide Action

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

It's possible to show/hide action on specific folders (right click with mouse) of the project ?

Cause for now I test if the folder is allowed by it's name and show an error message but action is show and take place on menu for all folders of the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. In your class that extends `AnAction`, you need to override the `update()` method and call `event.getPresentation().setVisible(false)` if the selected file is not relevant for your action.

Comment: Perfect thanks !!! Can you tell me how can I retrieve folder name except with e.getDataContext().getData(DataConstants.VIRTUAL_FILE) cause DataConstants.VIRTUAL_FILE is deprecated :/

Comment: e.getData(PlatformDataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE)